# Grabbing data from a specific element from a list in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to write some javascript/jQuery that will grab a link from reddit after clicking the upvote button.

As of right now, if I upvoted multiple things, it will only grab the link from the first specified class name in the returned jQuery list. Example:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('.arrow.upmod')) {
        var url = $(e).parent().parent().data('url');
        alert(url);
    }
});
```

So if I have 2 posts upvoted, it will only return the link comes first in the list. I'm trying to figure out how to grab ONLY the link that was most recently upvoted (so an eventListener that will ONLY grab the information on the post that was just upvoted).

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not put the event listener on the `.arrow.upmod` items?

Comment: e is an event. you probably meant $(this).parent... also, why not use jQuery to set up your events..

Comment: `var url = $(this).parent().parent().data('url');`

Comment: @adam-beck so you mean change the first line to: `document.addEventListener('.arrow.upmod',function(e) {`

Comment: @Shayd3 I think he means `$('.arrow.upmod').click(function() {
var url = $(this).parent().data('url');
alert(url);)};`. Not tested... but that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This does exactly what I needed:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if (e.target.matches('.arrow.upmod')) {
    var url = $(e.target).parent().parent().attr('data-url');
    alert(url);
    }
});
```